# jupyter notebook fails to start on Anaconda install on standalone non-networked computer

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install Anaconda python on a standalone non-networked computer. When I try to start the jupyter notebook, it fails, producing a blank page, an untitled.ipynb file and flashes a 404 html page.

The relevant line in the log seems to be

404 GET /undefined (::1)

What can I do to get this working?

ETA

I did a clean install and managed to capture the messages printed by jupyter to the console as it fails to start up. This is what I see

```
[I 12:53:19.510 NotebookApp] serving notebooks from local directory: c:\users\myname
[I 12:53:19.510 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 12:53:19.510 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 12:53:19.510 NotebookApp] Use control -c to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 12:53:33.252 NotebookApp] 404 GET /undefined (::1) 16.00ms referer=None 
[I 12:53:33.252 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
```

and at this point I am stuck. The notebook is there in the Explorer window, but there are no menu buttons or any indication that it is alive (apart from some options to print to pdf from Adobe.)

Comment: Are there any error messages in the JS console in the browser?

Comment: I am not sure I am looking in the right place, but the F12 console on Explorer gives the following messages-- HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=edge') ignored because document mode is already finalized -- LOG: API request failed (12029) error -- LOG: object OBJECT

Comment: Do you have another browser there to try on?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It's a shared, non-networked machine in a remote lab and I don't have admin priviledges.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the logging? What version of the notebook do you have (`jupyter notebook --version`)?

Comment: There is a lot in the log. Is the something specific I should be looking for? Is it saved to a file somewhere? The version is 4.1.0.

Comment: It is not written to a file by default, but you can redirect it with `jupyter notebook > log_file.txt`

Comment: Sorry, it took a while to get to this. I am on a windows machine. In a CMD.exe window that redirection doesn't work. I can note down what passes in the CMD window, if I knew what I was looking for.

Comment: [This says it does](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). There isn't something specific I'm expecting, I'm just trying to see if there's anything else out of the ordinary.